# Stacked Area Graph Using R and ggplot2 Has Holes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked area graph with r and ggplot2. I'd like it to look 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SPDL.png), but instead the [areas overlap and have holes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU928.png). I'm trying to ensure that the areas are stacked so that the area with the largest value in the most recent month (2016-05 in this case) are on the bottom.

Related posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916995/ggplot2-stacked-area-line-charts-producing-odd-lines-and-holes) seem to have holes in the data, which doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Here's sample code to recreate the issue:

```
sample.data <- structure(
  list(
    rank = structure(
      c(34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 34L), 
      .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"), 
      class = "factor"), 
    vendor = structure(
      c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
      .Label = c("34", "35"), 
      class = "factor"), 
    year.month = c("2015-12", "2016-01", "2015-11", "2015-12", "2016-01", "2015-10", "2016-03", "2016-02", "2015-10", "2016-04", "2015-11", "2016-05", "2016-04", "2016-03", "2016-02", "2016-05"), 
    value = c(431616L, 272224L, 229288L, 195284L, 155168L, 154194L, 149784L, 137302L, 126612L, 117408L, 94141L, 56161L, 54606L, 53173L, 49898L, 45348L)), 
  .Names = c("rank", "vendor", "year.month", "value"), 
  row.names = c(6L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 12L, 10L, 2L, 14L, 3L, 15L, 13L, 11L, 9L, 16L), 
  class = "data.frame"
)

ggplot(data = sample.data, aes(x = year.month, y = value, group = vendor, color = vendor, reorder(-value), fill=vendor)) +
  geom_area()
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try: + geom_area(position="dodge",stat="identity")

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
ggplot(data = sample.data[order(sample.data$vendor),], 
       aes(x = year.month, y = value, group = vendor, color = vendor, 
           reorder(-value), fill=vendor)) + geom_area()
```

You just had to order your data: `sample.data[order(sample.data$vendor),]`.

If you want to change the order of the graph, you have to "relevel" the vendor variable which is stored as a factor:

```
sample.data$vendor <- relevel(sample.data$vendor, ref="35")
```

Here is some code to figure out what vendor to set as the base level according to your criterion:

```
with(sample.data, sample.data[year.month=="2016-05", 
                        "vendor"][which.max(sample.data[year.month=="2016-05", "value"])])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I think that's really close, but I'm trying to ensure that the areas are stacked so that the area with the largest value in the most recent month (2016-05 in this case) is on the bottom. I tried substituting "value" in for "vendor" in a couple places, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Because your vendor variable is a factor, you need to use `relevel` to achieve this. See my code above.